# Inserting a pdf file in LaTeX

Tags: captions, pdf, pdfpages, includegraphics, center

Im trying to insert a PDF file in LaTeX and I'm having some problems.

Making a search here I have found several solutions, but none of them is completly working for me.

First of all I tried using `\usepackage{pdfpages}`, but the programme cant read it and it says "missing `\begin{document}`" when the order `\beign{document}` is there.

As it wasnt working for me I tried using:

```
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Fotos/Tablaprueba.pdf}
\end{center}
```

This way, I achieve inserting the file, but I have another problem. In the page it remains a huge space under the file inserted, and when I write some text down below, it appears several lines after the file inserted, and not immediatelly after. Also, I'd like to insert a caption after the file and I cant do it in that last way I described.

Comment: `\includegraphics` adds no space. The `center` environment adds a small amount.  Check that the space is not in the pdf that you are including

Comment: You cannot use `\caption`  except in floats.  Change `center`  by  `table`  and before  `\includegraphics`  add `\centering\caption{Mi prueba}\label{prueba}`. BTW, use always `\linewidth` instead of `\textwidth` to set the width of the images (you will notice the difference  working in two columns, for example). Also the "1" can be omitted (is the default).

Comment: Thank you so much Fran, it worked perfectly. Just one more question. With that enviroment, is there any option to insert one concrete page of the pdf file?